# Python programming error, elif statment syntax error Simple code

Tags: python, if-statement

```
name=input("Hello person, Whats your name?")
print("Hello", name)
print("Do you want to hear a story?", name)
choice=input("Yes, No?")
if choice==("yes" or "yes " or "Yes" or "Yes "):
    print("Ok", name,", listen up")    
print("There was once an old, old house at the top of a hill Sooooo high it was above the clouds")
choice2=input("What do you want to call the house?")
print("The old,",choice2,"was once owned by an old lady. ")

elif choice==("maybe"):
    print("You found an easter egg, congrats. PS this does nothing")
```

Whats wrong with this code?? It says in the idle shell syntax error. The last elif statement isn't working.

Comment: I need new eyes after seeing this `if choice==("yes" or "yes " or "Yes" or "Yes "):`

Comment: @ikaros45 is right; this relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true.

Comment: Indentation error after the if statement.

Comment: Try `if choice in ["yes","yes ","Yes","Yes "]` (although, what exactly are you planning for the case of more than a single space after the "yes"?).

Comment: try if choice.upper() == "YES". plenty of things wrong with that code mate.

Comment: @RuiLima still needs to strip white spaces: `choice.strip().upper() == 'YES'`

Answer (score 3):

This is a petty indentation issue, your print statements for the `if` blocks are not indented right and so the `elif` seems to be out of place. Note that python keeps [track of logical blocks](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html) by the indentation.

```
name=input("Hello person, Whats your name?")
print("Hello", name)
print("Do you want to hear a story?", name)
choice=input("Yes, No?")
if choice==("yes" or "yes " or "Yes" or "Yes "):
    print("Ok", name,", listen up")    
    print("There was once an old, old house at the top of a hill Sooooo high it was above the clouds")
    choice2=input("What do you want to call the house?")
    print("The old,",choice2,"was once owned by an old lady. ")

elif choice==("maybe"):
    print("You found an easter egg, congrats. PS this does nothing")
```

As already pointed out, `if choice==("yes" or "yes " or "Yes" or "Yes ")` is wrong, use `if choice.lower().strip() == "yes"` instead, or `if choice in ("yes", "yes ", "Yes", "Yes ")`.

If in case this is python 2, `input` will throw an error, use `raw_input` instead.
Also `print` with multiple statements will throw errors as well if used like a function, so change them from `print(statement_x, statement_y, statement_z)` to `print statement_x, statement_y, statement_z`

Comment: Thanks this worked! just needed to add four spaces at the if statement blocks and the code works.

Comment: This still has problems, `if choice==("yes" or "yes " or "Yes" or "Yes "):`

Comment: @Cyber Yeah, I know, but that has already been pointed out in comments to question. Other than that, if this is python 2, `input` will throw an error, `print` with multiple statements will throw errors as well.

Comment: Im using python 3 :P